# Finite-duration signal in the time domain, means what exactly in the frequency domain?

Tags: signal, fourier, sampling, signal-theory

I'm trying to understand exactly what restrictions a finite duration time domain signal has on its Fourier transform.

I found a helpful table in *The Fourier Transform and its Applications* by Ronald Bracewell:
[image: restrictions on spectrum]

Where the comb symbol is defined by the usual \$III(x) = \Sigma_n \delta(x - n) \$.

I know that a time domain signal sampled at rate \$M\$, by the normal Nyquist limit, will only have useful frequency content up to \$M/2\$. But this table seems to imply that the Fourier transform of such a signal will have frequency content up to \$M\$?

Similarly I'm confused about the Fourier domain equivalent of this statement (is there a name for this result? I haven't been able to find much searching "Fourier domain equivalent of Shannon-Nyquist"). I read the table as stating that a signal with duration \$2T=D\$ in the time domain will have a minimum resolvable frequency of \$1/T = 2/D\$ in the frequency domain. Is there a factor of 2 missing here as above, for useful information? Is there a Fourier-domain equivalent of Shannon-Nyquist?